# android how to make Tooltip for TextView

Tags: android, tooltip

I have a ListView in my activity. which consists of no of textviews. I performed a drag n drop action on textviews. So i want when i drag one item then the item above & below of it should be higlighted as Tooltip.
How can I do it. Please give me answer
Thanx

Answer (score 4):

you can draw a drawable with the below code and name it as tooltip.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="2dp" android:left="0dp" android:height="25dp" android:width="30dp">

<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/seekbar_color">
    </solid>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"></corners>
</shape>
</item>
<item android:left="7.5dp" android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp">

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid
                android:color="@color/seekbar_color" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

It will look something like this [image]

You can further use it in a textview as a background

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tooltip"
        android:text="0.5x"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:onClick="SaveSpeedMainClick"
        android:id="@+id/textview_activitysave_speed_segment_main"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: How can we make the arrow at bottom ?

Comment: <item android:left="7.5dp" android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp">

Comment: @KrishnaMeena for the second item make android:top="20dp"

Comment: @KrishnaMeena <item android:top="20dp" android:left="7.5dp" android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp"> This will make the second rectangle show arrow at the bottom. **android:top="20dp"**

Comment: Awesome. Remove 'android:height="25dp" android:width="30dp"' from first layer. So it will fill the view in which it will be set. Any tool used for creating such views?

Comment: Can you suggest how can we draw a colored, continuous border around this view?

Comment: how can I move it left || center?

Comment: is there anyone who can explain the drawable drawn above?  how is it showing a tooltip on top when its having <item android:left="7.5dp" android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp"> ?? @NitinAgarwal

Comment: this has fixed height and width text will not fit inside this

Comment: When i set the drawable view to text view tip get cut from the top little

Answer (score 0):

As in android developers document,

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setTooltipText("Send an email");

Comment: Yes, but only for Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher